# Caliburn.Micro 2.0/3.0 Bind.Model replacement

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

What is the recommended replacement for usage of the Bind.Model tag from version 1.x?

I am finally migrating some code from Caliburn 1.x to 3.0.  The migration documentation says that Bind.Model is obsolete and shouldn't be used any more.  However, I have some common user controls (Header, Footer, Keyboards) that I use in multiple views.  In 1.x I used the Bind.Model tag to be able to explicitly connect the View to its ViewModel and process the events/actions.  In 3.0, it still accepts the Bind.Model tag and this seems to work OK for the data properties, but the button/action processing is not working properly.

I tried using the  as suggested here: [Dialog view containing two Caliburn.Micro views?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4412677/dialog-view-containing-two-caliburn-micro-views)

This gives me a message in the window that says it can't find the View.

Any other references I have been able to find for embedding views use the Bind.Model tag.

Answer (score 0):

Not all use cases of `Bind.Model` are obsolete, pre `2.0.0` versions supported a syntax where you could do something like:

```
<SomeControl cm:Bind.Model="SomeViewModel" />
```

where the value was a string that caused a request to the IoC container to a view model registered under "SomeViewModel".

This use case was made deprecated in `2.0.0` and removed in `3.0.0`.

The use case of an explicit binding as in:

```
<SomeControl cm:Bind.Model="{Binding SomeViewModel}" />
```

is still 100% supported with no plans to change this.